# How to adding our own sorting to a view on Drupal?

Tags: views

I have develop a drupal view with table format.

- Here table rows are **Name** and **Date**.
- I am sorting a **Name** column with default sorting in views,it's working fine.
- But when user click on views page automatically views page redirected to default sorting in views.
- Here problem is when user click on sorting with (asc/desc) that order permanently store in database.

how can we achieve this.

Comment: Are you using views content or query caching?

Comment: i am using views content

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of your view setup?

Comment: I think you just have to click the downward arrow next to the add button of the sort field and re-arrange your sorts so that the sort by name is listed as #1.

Comment: please see this question for screen shot: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147071/how-to-custom-sort-name-by-alphabetically-in-drupal-views

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your view query with [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) to add your custom sorting.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_query_alter
 * @param type $view
 * @param type $query 
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  //simple example: change the order of the master display
  //if you want to do it only  on a certain display add something 
  // like  "&&$view->current_display == 'panel_page_1'"
  if ($view->name == 'VIEWNAME') {

    //to find out what the fieldname ist: use devel and add your desired field as 
    //first filter ( =>orderby[0]). install devel and uncomment the next line
    //dpm($view->query->orderby)

    $view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "CASE FIELD_NAME WHEN 'apple' THEN 1 WHEN 'zebra' THEN 2 WHEN 'banna' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate this one plz .$view->query->orderby[0]['field']